# Loops and variable scope in R

Tags: r, variables, for-loop, functional-programming

I have following for loop in R:

```
v = c(1,2,3,4)
s = create.some.complex.object()
for (i in v){
   print(i)
   s = some.complex.function.that.updates.s(s)
}
# s here has the right content.
```

Needless to say, this loop is horribly slow in R.
I tried to write it in functional style:

```
   lapply(v, function(i){
      print(i)
      s = some.complex.function.that.updates.s(s)
   })
   # s wasn't updated.
```

But this doesn't work, because `s` is passed by value and not by reference.
I only need the result of the last iteration, not all of the intermediate steps.
How do I formulate the first loop in R-style?

Mulone

Comment: Try the other assignment operator: `s <<-`

Comment: @Thomas this would make his code even slower. Why don't just take the list of result as `lapply` uses to return?

Comment: `lapply` probably wouldn't make your loop much faster anyway. Generally you would use `lapply` (and friends) when each iteration has no side-effects, or to avoid having to pre-allocate an object; here you explicitly have such a side-effect.

Comment: @Michele I missed the part about speed. I'm confused though about what the OP actually wants: each iteration or just the final result of the last iteration.

Comment: @Thomas I was too. Just understood he needs the final. Probably `for` is the best way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   lapply(v, function(i){
      print(i)
      s = some.complex.function.that.updates.s(s)
      return(s)
   })
```

the result will be a list of object `s` created for each value of `v`. Even if it should have passed the value of `v` anyway cause it was the last operation performed by the function.

Comment: This would be ok, but the s object can be very large, and I can't afford to save it many times. I would like to work on one instance of the object, as I do in the for loop.

Comment: @Mulone hold on, so you don't need `s` object per each value of `v`? But to recalculate it every time?

Comment: @Mulone if so, probably `for` is the fastest and most straightforward solution. Otherwise, you can try the `Rcpp` package and write a `c++` code for you `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't afford to create it many times then there are not a lot of options. It is hard to say as well without seeing the object that you are operating on. If the object is growing/appending you could collect the intermediate results and do the appending at the end. If it is actually mutating you should try to get away from the pass value and use reference classes (http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/ReferenceClasses). Then the function that modifies it will actually be a method you just call n times.

Answer (score 0):

Is the loop itself really the problem? Or is it rather the time the execution of some.complex.function.that.updates.s needs?
Some R programers will jump through hoops to avoid loops but have a look at this example:

```
f <- function(a) a/1.001
loop <- function(n) { s = (1/f(1)^n); for (i in 1:n) s <- f(s); s}
system.time(loop(1E7))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.011   0.030   7.008
```

This is 0.7 micro seconds (on a MacBook Pro) per call of a very trivial function in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
v = c(1,2,3,4)
s = create.some.complex.object()    
lapply(v, function(i){
    print(i)
    s <<- some.complex.function.that.updates.s(s)
}) |> invisible()
```

Use of the `<<-` operator can sometimes get you into trouble and is (somewhat) discouraged, but when I want to mimic a for loop with side-effects this is a pattern I have found useful.

```
v = c(1,2,3,4)
s = create.some.complex.object()    
lapply(v, function(i){
    print(i)
    assign('s', some.complex.function.that.updates.s(s), envir = .GlobalEnv)
}) |> invisible()
```

Using `assign` allows you to avoid the use of `<<-` operator. Using `<<-` is significantly faster than invoking the `assign` function. For performance reasons in more intensive applications it is *very much* worth it to replace sequential `for` loops with vectorized operations as the median execution time of `lapply` can be several orders of magnitude faster! Here are some toy benchmarks to support this assertion:

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark({
  s <- 1    
  lapply(v, function(i) {
    s <<- s + i
  })
}, times = 1e4, unit = 'microseconds')
```

Median: ~ 4 microseconds

```
v <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark({
  s <- 1    
  for(i in v) {
    s <- s + i
  }
}, times = 1e4, unit = 'microseconds')
```

Median: ~ 1488 microseconds